# Angular2 : 'Fetch as Google' doesn't render page

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, fetch-as-google, angular.js

I am working on Angular2 based web app. I used Angular CLI to generate app and then to build it for prod. I have hosted website on AWS S3 & Cloudfront. When I use 'Fetch as Google' tool from the webmaster, it shows only `Loading...`.

[image]

Website loads properly on the browser. I had read that Googlebot reads Javascript and rede Isn't Googlebot able to crawl my website?

Comment: Please don't cross post to multiple stack exchange sites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165016/angular2-app-fetch-as-google-doesnt-load-page-content

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it was cross posted.